# Mini-pc compatible with Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am looking for a mini-pc compatible with Ubuntu. It is to be used as a "infoscreen" (displaying an activity list). By compatible i mean that drivers must be available, at least for graphics and wifi.

It must have the following capabilities:

- Run MonoDevelop for C# compatibility*
- Run LAMP (Apache, MySQL and PHP)*
- Have wifi - preferably built-in.
- Preferably resolution up to 1920x1080
- Low price :-)

* I know this is possible with Ubuntu, but someone might suggest an Android mini-pc or some other kind, that i don't know of. As long as the above is possible, i don't care which brand or type it is.

Can anyone recommend a specific mini-pc or maybe a brand?

I've tried the Zotac Zbox Nano VD01 Plus, but that was no succes. Only old version of Ubuntu were supported and i never got the wifi driver fully working.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe you could make your `Zotac` board work. Did you consider compiling a recent kernel (3.9) and finding some wifi driver for it?

Comment: Maybe i should have mentioned, that i have no experience with Linux besides what i learned from trying to make the Zotac work. But when i searched for solutions, i found out that i was not exacly the only one having problems with the Zotac and Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know it, but from what I've read a [MSI FM2-A75IA-E53](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/FM2-A75IA-E53.html) with a AMD A6-5600K processor should not have many problems. However, I believe you should take time to learn Linux, and install it on your development laptop or desktop machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian. it doesn't have wifi, but there are adapters.